# How to build only a subset of packages in a workspace?

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a project with various packages for interfacing with hardware that won't build unless their SDKs are installed. So this means every developer has to install all these SDKs for hardware they are never going to see.

Is there some way of marking these packages as "production only" so they aren't built or required except when a "production" flag is set?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354919/how-to-build-only-a-subset-of-packages-in-a-workspace?/) by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2020-06-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-15**:
Suggestion: change the title of your question to the actual question (ie: how to build only a subset of packages), instead of mentioning a potential solution you came up with already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there some way of marking these packages as "production only" so they aren't built or required except when a "production" flag is set?

No, there isn't.

What you *could* do is explicitly ask it to build only a subset of packages (which results in the same behaviour, but uses more appropriate ways to express your intention).

You'd want to use `catkin_tools` for this though.

See [catkin build: Build Packages - Building Subsets of Packages](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_build.html#building-subsets-of-packages). To go beyond individual packages and use profiles with specific sets of packages (to ignore or to actually build), you can use [white/black listing](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_config.html#whitelisting-and-blacklisting-packages).

If you absolutely don't want to use `catkin_tools`, you could look into the white/black listing functionality of `catkin_make`. See the comments on #q54178 for an example and #q285341. It's much less convenient than the implementation in `catkin_tools` though.

> So this means every developer has to install all these SDKs for hardware they are never going to see.

But your description makes me ask: why do those developers have those packages in their workspace then?

---

Edit:

> The project is a catkin workspace (in a git repo.), developers branch and merge the project in order to develop for it and test it. Is not a typical way to develop for ROS projects?

No. Not at all.

In fact, I would almost say: **never** version entire workspaces (by putting them in a single repository).

See also #q264600 (and the Q&As linked from that). And #q347421 for the ROS 2 version (which isn't really any different).

I'd recommend to take a look at tools like `vcstool`, `rosdep`, `.rosinstall` files, `rosinstall_generator` et al.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) on 2020-06-15**:
The project is a catkin workspace (in a git repo.), developers branch and merge the project in order to develop for it and test it. Is not a typical way to develop for ROS projects?